# Respawn system in Call of Duty United Offensive (CoD: UO)

Tags: call-of-duty, call-of-duty-united-offensive

Me and my friends have been playing Call of Duty United Offensive online for quite a while now. We really like the headquarters mode, but can really figure out how the respawning system works. There are 2 things we're wondering about:

a) When do you get respawned?
I know that there are rounds that last 45 seconds. When that passes everyone who's dead gets respawned. But sometimes some players are respawned before that time passes. What I don't get is when that happens. Sometimes it seems like if you die in the first few seconds of the round you get immediately respawned. Sometimes that's not the case.

b) Location of the respawn.
The only thing about the location of the respawn I've been able to deduct is that if the radio is you'll get respawned close to it if that's your teams' radio otherwise you'll be respawned on the other side of the map. And even that isn't true all the time. But other times people get respawned next to opponent's radio.

Can someone help me clear this confusion up?
Me and my mates would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. If the server is setup to allow reinforcements then you can/will be re-spawned before the timer runs out. If this is turned off no one will re-spawn till the next HQ. The amount of time till the re-spawn is set per server, so can't say for sure what it is. But say you have to hold the HQ for 45 seconds then normally IIRC you can re spawn after 30 seconds. Also you re-spawn in the order/time you die, so if player a dies right as HQ is captured, he has a MAX of 30 seconds, then player B dies he also has a MAX of 30 seconds, thus spawning after player a by x amount of time.

If the HQ is destroyed during this time everyone re-spawns right away. There are a few exceptions I believe, i.e if you die before HQ is captured, you'll spawn right away at beginning to help hold/capture it.

B. You get re-spawned next to your teammates, if everyone is dead then it's the other side of the map, if they're alive you'll spawn closest to the furthest player from the obj.

Hope that's clear :D

Comment: This explains quite a lot. Especially the 'MAX 30 seconds' rule. BTW does the order of death work with your teams or does it work globally?
I'll keep this in mind when I'm playing with my friends next and see if there are any other cases I can't explain. Thanks for now :)

Comment: @gligoran order of death is on your team. same for the other team, both teams don't always have the same re-spawn timer. i.e sometimes the defending teams has longer re-spawn timer then the attacking team. etc...